# Decompress Large Number of Files on S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have 300,000 gzipped JSON text files on s3 and am trying to figure out the most efficient way to decompress them and keep them on S3. I could download, decompress, upload, delete gzipped version but that is proving to be very slow.

Any ideas?

Comment: don't decompress them

Comment: Vorsprung makes a point, it is good to question why you are doing this... there are many tools that work well with compressed files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider writing a lambda function to perform the download/decompress/upload function and then use something like S3 Batch operations to apply that lambda to all of your S3 objects.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-s3-batch-operations/